# Switching between views not working for iPhone 5.1 (XCode 4.3.2)

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to develop an iPhone app that uses 4 views(View-based app), and I want to navigate from one view to the other. It would be ideal if for example the Submit ID button automatically sent a message to UIViewController to switch to View 2, and selecting a cell in View 2 would load View 3.

See a screenshot of the Storyboard [here.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17432601/Screen%20Shot%202012-04-26%20at%2017.08.16.png)

I'm not sure how to do that, so I've tried using a separate button to switch between views, but that isn't working either and I can't figure out why.

You can have a look at the source code [which I've uploaded to Dropbox](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17432601/Project%20C.zip).

Comment: You cant expect people to download, unzip and work through your whole project. Can you include more detail in your question? What is the view switching code you have tried to implement? You have a lot of push segues in your storyboard, but it is not possible to tell if your view controllers are embedded in a navigation controller. If you want to switch between 4 views in any order, should you use a tab bar controller?

Answer (score 1):

First, I would suggest posting your code in your question. As appreciative as I'm sure other people are that you provided a dropbox link to the code, most people presumably have little interest in downloading the file to their computer, unzipping, and launching the project (me being one of them).

That being said, let's make sure you're clear on Storyboards and the general view controller hierarchy principles. You have, in your storyboard, four UIViewControllers dragged out into your workspace. So, you're not switching the views of a single UIViewController, telling it to switch from View1 to View2 to View3 and so on. You need to be telling the view controller hierarchy (which, in your case, probably needs to be managed by a UINavigationController), to push and/or pop view controller on and off its stack. It appears that you have some segues set up between your view controllers. Are you calling `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` in your code? Alternatively, you could hook up the Submit ID button to perform a push segue to View Controller 2 in much the same manner.

Once you have that working, you can override `prepareForSegue:sender:` to send information from ViewController1 to ViewController2 and so on.